# Code and feature conditional on Rust version or specific compiler feature

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Rust 1.63 stabilized const `std::sync::Mutex::new()`. Till date to have global flag preventing parallel execution would look like (example):

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
static GLOBAL_FLAG: Lazy<Mutex<()>> = Lazy::new(Default::default);
```

while in since 1.63 it can look like this and the dependency isn't required anymore in `Cargo.toml`:

```rust
static GLOBAL_FLAG: Mutex<()> = Mutex::new(());
```

Now, the **question is** how to make use of both conditionally, depending on either:
which version of the compiler is used to build the crate
or
whether the feature is stable (I struggle to find it's correct name at the moment)?

I was looking at [`cfg_rust_features`](https://docs.rs/cfg_rust_features/latest/cfg_rust_features/) crate, but the part where dependency isn't required by `Cargo.toml` remains mystery. Any hints welcome.

Comment: The general answer for this is to have a "rustc_1_63" feature that enables the dependency and tells your code to assume that version of Rust. See what tinyvec does [here](https://github.com/Lokathor/tinyvec/blob/a711c72eef6d555ebc7bbbe78bf5039e72f790ac/src/tinyvec.rs#L9)

Comment: Is this for a top-level application? It would probably be best to just [set a minimum Rust version in your `Cargo.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-rust-version-field)

Comment: Probably, @PitaJ, but I'm looking if it's possible to support older with dependencies and newer without. I just want to learn if and how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically accomplished by:

1. Detecting the Rust version (using [`rustversion`](https://crates.io/crates/rustversion/)/[`rustc_version`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc_version/)) or the required feature (using [`autocfg`](https://crates.io/crates/autocfg/)),
2. Making the fallback dependency (`once_cell`) optional, and
3. Emitting an error if the required Rust feature is missing *and* the fallback dependency is also missing.

For example, using `rustversion`:

```rust
#[rustversion::since(1.63)]
mod private {
    use std::sync::Mutex;
    pub static GLOBAL_FLAG: Mutex<()> = Mutex::new(());
}

#[rustversion::before(1.63)]
#[cfg(feature = "once_cell")]
mod private {
    use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
    use std::sync::Mutex;
    pub static GLOBAL_FLAG: Lazy<Mutex<()>> = Lazy::new(Default::default);
}

#[rustversion::before(1.63)]
#[cfg(not(feature = "once_cell"))]
compile_error!(
    "The \"once_cell\" feature must be enabled for Rust compiler versions prior to 1.63."
);
```

When compiling on 1.62 without `once_cell`, this emits

```
error: The "once_cell" feature must be enabled for Rust compiler versions prior to 1.63.
  --> src/main.rs:18:1
   |
18 | / compile_error!(
19 | |     "The \"once_cell\" feature must be enabled for Rust compiler versions prior to 1.63."
20 | | );
   | |_^
```

*Note: the use of `mod private` seen above is not strictly necessary, but it reduces the number of attributes and ensures that the relevant compile error is the only error emitted. You can `pub use private::GLOBAL_FLAG` to put it back in scope.*